# SQL partition the dataset and pick until a column value changes to a particular value in each dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a set of rows as below

*select [Id]
        , Entity
        , Time
        , Code
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Entity ORDER BY Time DESC) RowNumber 
from EntityExample
ORDER BY Entity, RowNumber DESC*

[image: Query result]

Now, The Goal is to retrieve rows in each entity type until the Code column value changes to "Denied".
And the condition is to sort by Time column descending in each entity type and pick the topmost rows until the Code column value changes to "Denied"

How can we achieve this in SQL?

This is the resulting snapshot to achieve

[image: Result snapshot]

Note: Due to privacy issues I have created an example dataset and uploaded it. So the number of entities and number of rows related to each entity is varied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select ee.*
from EntityExample ee
where ee.time < (select min(ee2.time)
                 from EntityExample ee2
                 where ee2.entity = ee.entity and
                       ee2.code = 'Denied'
                );
```